# How to Map these Classes into a Relational data model?

Tags: oop, orm, database-abstraction

I am doing a simple blog project for which I've come up with the following object class structure.

```
user class (email address, password)

blog_entry class ( title, body, dateposted, state[draft, published] )

comment class ( comment, date posted )

category class ( category name )
```

### object relationships

1. a user can post zero or more blog entries, a blog entry belong to one and only one user
2. a user can publish one or more comments, a comment belong to one and only one user
3. a comment belong to a one and only one blog entry, a blog entry can have zero or more comments
4. a blog entry belong to one and only one category, category can exist without a blog entry

I need to know how to map these object structure(including relationships) into a relational data model for mysql. Since this is my first MVC project I don't have a clear understanding how to get this done properly.

Pl. advise.

PS: I've come up with following data model. Appreciate your ideas on this:

```
users
 - id
 - email_address
 - password

categories
 - id
 - category_name

blog_posts
 - id
 - post_title
 - post_contents
 - post_dateposted
 - post_state
 - users_id
 - categories_id

comments
 - id
 - comment
 - comment_dateposted
 - blog_posts_id
 - users_id
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use Repository pattern,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/631668/Learning-MVC-Part-Repository-Pattern-in-MVC-App
by using this you can simply devide your modules & can work in a well manner.

Comment: Basically, every class becomes a table; the relationships become foreign keys.

Comment: FYI: the implementation details of your data persistence has **nothing** to do with MVC architectural design pattern.